# Can't use the model Entity for Room. Tried the following constructors but they failed to match

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I ask you for help. I've already spent a lot of time solving the problem, but haven't solved it yet.

I would like to place this model in the Room.
But I get problems all the time.

I've tried removing annotation

```
@Parcelize
```

But the result hasn't changed.

```
@Entity
@Parcelize
data class UserRepositoryItem (
    var archive_url: String,
    var archived: Boolean,
    var assignees_url: String,
    var blobs_url: String,
    var branches_url: String,
    var clone_url: String,
    var collaborators_url: String,
    var comments_url: String,
    var commits_url: String,
    var compare_url: String,
    var contents_url: String,
    var contributors_url: String,
    var created_at: String,
    var default_branch: String,
    var deployments_url: String,
    var description: String,
    var disabled: Boolean,
    var downloads_url: String,
    var events_url: String,
    var fork: Boolean,
    var forks: Int,
    var forks_count: Int,
    var forks_url: String,
    var full_name: String,
    var git_commits_url: String,
    var git_refs_url: String,
    var git_tags_url: String,
    var git_url: String,
    var has_downloads: Boolean,
    var has_issues: Boolean,
    var has_pages: Boolean,
    var has_projects: Boolean,
    var has_wiki: Boolean,
    var homepage: String,
    var hooks_url: String,
    var html_url: String,
    var id: Int,
    var issue_comment_url: String,
    var issue_events_url: String,
    var issues_url: String,
    var keys_url: String,
    var labels_url: String,
    var language: String?,
    var languages_url: String,
    @Ignore var license: License,
    var merges_url: String,
    var milestones_url: String,
    var mirror_url: String?,
    var name: String,
    var node_id: String,
    var notifications_url: String,
    var open_issues: Int,
    var open_issues_count: Int,
    @Ignore var owner: Owner,
    var `private`: Boolean,
    var pulls_url: String,
    var pushed_at: String,
    var releases_url: String,
    var size: Int,
    var ssh_url: String,
    var stargazers_count: Int,
    var stargazers_url: String,
    var statuses_url: String,
    var subscribers_url: String,
    var subscription_url: String,
    var svn_url: String,
    var tags_url: String,
    var teams_url: String,
    var trees_url: String,
    var updated_at: String,
    var url: String,
    var watchers: Int,
    var watchers_count: Int
): Parcelable {

    @IgnoredOnParcel
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var repoId: Long = 0
}
```

I get an error every time.

```
    error: Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
public final class UserRepositoryItem implements android.os.Parcelable {
             ^
  Tried the following constructors but they failed to match:
```

I will greatly appreciate any answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Change somehow the name `private` of your field. It's a keyword in Java, so there could be problems.

```
.........................
var `private`: Boolean, <------ that's not good idea
.........................
```

2. Move your fields annotated with `@Ignore` to the body of class.

```
...........................
): Parcelable {

    @IgnoredOnParcel
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var repoId: Long = 0
    @Ignore var owner: Owner <---------- move all your @Ignore fields here
...........................
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
@Entity(tableName = "student")
data class Student @JvmOverloads constructor(        //key point
    var name: String,  
    var age: Int,   
    var gpa: Double,
    var isSingle: Boolean,

    @Ignore                           
    var isSelected: Boolean = false,

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)        //primary key field must be placed at the end
    var id: Long = 0                     
)
```